# Creating sentences from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have the following dataset:

```
    pos   sentence_idx      word
    NNS     1.0            Thousands
    IN      1.0            of
    NNS     1.0            demonstrators
    VBP     1.0            have
    VBN     1.0            marched
... ... ... ...
    PRP     47959.0        they
    VBD     47959.0        responded
    TO      47959.0        to
    DT      47959.0        the
    NN      47959.0        attack
```

I want to create sentences(for this I have to use sentence_idx). I can do this using the following code:

```
sent = []
for i in df['sentence_idx'].unique():
  sent.append([(w,t) for w,t in zip(df[df['sentence_idx'] == i]['word'].values.tolist(),df[df['sentence_idx'] == i]['pos'].values.tolist())])
```

But first of all it's not efficient(using for loops instead of numpy/pandas functions) and it looks ugly.
How can I do it more efficiently?

**EDIT:**
The result should be sentences, where each element is a tuple(word, pos):

```
[[('Thousands', 'NNS'),
  ('of', 'IN'),
  ('demonstrators', 'NNS'),
  ('have', 'VBP'),
  ('marched', 'VBN'),
  ('through', 'IN'),
  ('London', 'NNP'),
  ('to', 'TO'),
  ('protest', 'VB'),
  ('the', 'DT'),
  ('war', 'NN'),
  ('in', 'IN'),
  ('Iraq', 'NNP'),
  ('and', 'CC'),
  ('demand', 'VB'),
  ('withdrawal', 'NN'),
  ('British', 'JJ'),
  ('troops', 'NNS'),
  ('from', 'IN'),
  ('that', 'DT'),
  ('country', 'NN'),
  ('.', '.')],
 [('Families', 'NNS'),
  ('of', 'IN'),
  ('soldiers', 'NNS'),
  ('killed', 'VBN'),
  ('in', 'IN'),
  ('the', 'DT'),
  ('conflict', 'NN'),
  ('joined', 'VBD'),
  ('protesters', 'NNS'),
  ('who', 'WP'),
  ('carried', 'VBD'),
  ('banners', 'NNS'),
  ('with', 'IN'),
  ('such', 'JJ'),
  ('slogans', 'NNS'),
  ('as', 'IN'),
  ('"', '``'),
  ('Bush', 'NNP'),
  ('Number', 'NN'),
  ('One', 'CD'),
  ('Terrorist', 'NN'),
  ('and', 'CC'),
  ('Stop', 'VB'),
  ('Bombings', 'NNS'),
  ('.', '.')],...
```

Comment: So what you are looking to do is creating `tuples` of `(word, pos)`, not sentences? i.e. `[[('Thousands', 'NNS'), ('of', 'IN'), ...], ...]`?

Comment: @r.ook I am sorry, forgot to add. Thank you, I edited my post

Comment: You may want to create a df with your sentence with rows being words then merge on your primary df

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
def compute(_):
    return [*zip(_['word'], _['pos'])]

df.groupby('sentence_idx').apply(compute).values.tolist()
```

Comment: thank you for you answer! But can you explain * near zip?

Comment: Sure thing, [*...] is just syntactic sugar for list(...)

Comment: [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip) & [`* operator`](https://realpython.com/python-kwargs-and-args/#unpacking-with-the-asterisk-operators)

Answer (score 1):

Unsure of efficiency, but here are some ways to accomplish this:

```
df.groupby('sentence_idx')[['word', 'pos']].apply(lambda x: list(zip(*zip(*x.values.tolist())))).tolist()

df.groupby('sentence_idx').apply(lambda x: x[['word', 'pos']].apply(tuple, axis=1).tolist())

df.groupby('sentence_idx').apply(lambda x: [tuple(y) for y in x[['word', 'pos']].values]).tolist()
```

If you don't necessarily need it as a `tuple` (i.e. a `list` will do) it's much simpler:

```
df.groupby('sentence_idx').apply(lambda x: x[['word', 'pos']].values.tolist()).tolist()
```

Comment: `apply` is slow for large dataframes and generally has worse performance than list comprehensions